# How to use recursion to determine if path exists between two nodes in graph?

Tags: c, algorithm, graph-theory, graph-traversal

I'm trying to implement a function `pathExists` which takes in a graph ADT 'g' as input, as well as two vertices `a` and `b`. If a path exists between the two vertices, then the function returns 1, otherwise it returns 0. I'm unsure how exactly to do this. I've implemented a Depth First Search (DFS) algorithm below which will generate `int *visited`, an array containing the order in which nodes are visited. I'm just wondering how I can use this algorithm to actually write the `pathExists` function. Thanks!

EDIT: Attempt-

```
void dfsR(Graph g, int v); 
int *visited;  // array of visited
int order; 


int PathExists(Graph g, int src, int dest)
{

    int i;
    order = 1; 
    visited = malloc(sizeof(int)*g->nV); 

    for(i=0; i<g->nV; i++){
        visited[i] = -1; 
    }

    dfsR(g, src);
    int connected = 0; 


    if(visited[dest]!=-1){
        connected = 1;
    }


   return connected;
}

void dfsR(Graph g, int v){ 

    visited[v] = order++; 
    int w; 
    for(w=0; w<g->nV; w++){
        if(!hasEdge(g, v,w)){
            continue; 
        }
        if(!visited[w]){
            dfsR(g, w); 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Suppose you perform a depth-first search starting at one of your two nodes.  There is a path between them if and only and the other was visited during that search.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Does it matter which node you start at? Does one need to be necessarily less than the other?

Comment: As this is currently written, I don't think you can tell. You set `visited[v]` to the order in which vertex `v` is visited by the DFS, but you only `malloc` that array, you never initialize its values. It contains arbitrary data and might well contain the sequence `1, 2, ..., nV(g)`, which could make it appear as though a totally unconnected graph were fully connected. If `visited[k] <= nV(g)`, there is no way to know whether it was set by DFS or whether it happened to have that value upon allocation.

Comment: @Patrick87 so what should everything be initialised to? -1 perhaps?

Comment: @novice That would work. 0 should work, too. Basically, anything will work provided that it's guaranteed not to be in the range `1, 2, ..., nV(g)`.

Comment: @novice you could use `calloc` to initialize your array. It doesn't matter which of the two nodes you start at since you visit every node that is possible to  visit in the graph from the starting point, meaning that if the two nodes are visited, then a path exists. 

For initialization, any value that is different from the two you expect works. I personally would use a `define` with 3 values 

You have to start from a node because you are not sure that a random entry point might not let you visit any of them, meaning that you wouldn't know where it could be.

Comment: I updated question to include my attempt, but it's still not working for some reaosn

Comment: You set `visited` to `-1` after running `dfsR` so all your visited nodes are set to -1

Comment: Oops... thanks, my bad!

Comment: Hmm strange, still not working

Comment: `!visited[w]` is always true, because you are using -1 and numbers greater than 1. That condition is true only when `visited[w]` is 0!

Comment: @RobertoTrani Ahhh of course! Now it works, thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest this faster solution.
The first hint is to avoid to waste time if you have already visited the destination node, or you are at one hop from it. The second hint is to use as less global variables as possible (as a general rule). Hence, my proposed solution is the following one:

```
typedef unsigned char bool;
#define true  1
#define false 0

bool dfsR(Graph g, int v, int dest, bool * visited);

bool PathExists(Graph g, int src, int dest)
{
    bool connected = false;  // result
    bool * visited = 0;  // array of visited nodes

    if (src == dest) {
        return true;
    }

    // initialize the support array
    visited = malloc(g->nV);
    memset(visited, false, g->nV);

    // call the recursive depth first search
    connected = dfsR(g, src, dest, visited);

    // free the memory from the support array
    free(visited);

    return connected;
}

bool dfsR(Graph g, int v, int dest, bool * visited){ 
    visited[v] = 1;

    // check if there is a direct edge toward dest before going on with the recursion
    if (hasEdge(g, v, dest)) {
        return true;
    }
    // try to find it recursively
    bool connected;
    for(int w=0; w<g->nV; w++) {
        if(hasEdge(g, v, w) && !visited[w]) {
            if (dfsR(g, w, dest, visited)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```